# Join two tables and insert value in a new table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm a novice. I need to know whether its possible in hive to join two tables (say customer_table and issues_table based on CustomedId column) and insert value in a new table in hive using insert overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible use the CTAS (`create table new_table as select ...`) syntax.

> create table new_table as select * from customer_table, issues_table where customer_table.CustomedId = issues_table.CustomedId;

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to run it in production. I have millions of records and it works without any hassle and quick too. Fully tested.

```
create table new_table as select * from customer_table t1 where t1.CustomedId NOT IN (Select t2.CustomedId FROM issues_table t2);
```